# What to look for in a pocket calculator for a Graduate level statistics course midterm / final

Tags: anova, inference, descriptive-statistics

Soon I'll be sitting for a midterm (and then the dreaded final) for a graduate class in Statistics.

It's open book / notes but I'll be needing a calculator -- something I've not used for years.

Any thoughts on what features I should look for when shopping for one. I've always wanted to own and use an [HP 10 series calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-10C_series) but I was struck with sticker shock when I looked them up on eBay.

Since a tag does not exist for this topic, I'll be tagging it with topics that I'll be examined on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly more suitable for the community wiki

Comment: Regarding your flag on the appropriateness of such question here, it was closed as off topic because there's no statistical issue. It could also be considered too localized. However, feel free to reach our chat room, [Ten Fold](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold), and ask around.

Answer (score 1):

The best person to ask would be your teacher since they will know more about what will be expected on the exams than we would.  At the minimum you will want one with a square root key (but many free ones and very cheap ones have that now).

Given that, in general anything that is more complicated than can be done on a \$20 calculator will generally be done using a computer, so you should not need to spend much on the calculator.  There are several calculators between \$10 and \$20 that have a statistics mode which makes it easier to calculate things like means and standard deviations (and sometimes correlatios and regressions).

When I write exam questions I will either provide computer output, access to a computer, or make things simple enough that a calculator with a square root key is sufficient.  You should not need a really expensive one, but check with the teacher to make sure (their style may differ from mine).